# Does Stag's Leap allow a Full Attack afterward?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, movement, attack, ranger

The [Skirmisher](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/skirmisher/) ability Stags Leap is:

> Stags Leap: As a free action, the Ranger can attempt a running jump without moving
>   10 feet before the jump.

This is a 10 ft pounce but I am wondering if it is possible to jump as well and still get the full attack.

I checked the Acrobatic page and found:

> An Acrobatics check is made as part of another action or as a reaction
>   to a situation.

Additionally the Skirmisher Ability Surprise Shift gives you an additional 5ft movement as a swift action

> Surprise Shift (Ex): The Ranger can move 5 feet as a swift action.
>   This movement does not provoke attacks of opportunity and does not
>   count as a 5-foot step.

So, is it possible to use Stags Leap to move 10ft as a free action, Surprise Shift as a swift action, additionally jump e.g. 20ft (DC 20) and use [Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat-final/) to get a 40ft, still being able to perform a full round action?

Comment: I find it interesting that you consistently typo'd the ability as "Stag's Leaf" no less than 3 times.  Are you aware that it is actually "Stag's Leap"?

Comment: Now I am! :) Any idea of an answer?

Comment: I have presented my take on the matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, the jump still takes your actions.**

It is somewhat counter-intuitive that Stag's Leap says that it works "as a free action".  This alleged free action is merely the activation of the ability which *grants the right to attempt* to begin a jump from a standing position, not to perform the entire jump instantly.  Jumping still requires using movement actions as normal.  The only reason it is deemed an "action" is because the Trick has a limited number of uses per day.  **The "free action" is the timing trigger for reducing the charges of the ability by 1, not for the jump itself.**

Additionally, don't be confused by the numbers.  Stag's Leap does not allow you to jump 10 feet.  Rather, it allows you to jump whatever distance you normally would, just without a running start (which is normally a 10 foot minimum).  You can jump however far your ranger normally could with a running start (which could be quite far) - you'll just need to spend the time to pull  it off.

Comment: I must agree… yet does *Pathfinder* ever make it clear that jumping requires a move action? I mean, I know *3.5e* did—and had rules for how one's jumping movement interacts with one's normal movement—, but are those rules still in *Pathfinder* somewhere? (As written, for instance, the Acrobatics skill seems to allow even *off-turn* jumps by taking a free action off-turn to speak then making an acrobatics skill  check to jump "as part of another action"—that free action that's been used to speak!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I am uncertain whether it's properly documented.  I admit I'm more going off of what I see as common sense abuse-avoidance.  I could be wrong, but it's an interpretation.

Comment: I totally think you're right… according to *3.5e* rules. I'm just wondering if *Pathfinder* assumed (still assumes?) that its audience is so familiar with its antecedent that the game doesn't need to state such *obvious* rules or if such rules are buried elsewhere. In other words, I think you're right, but I wish the game came out and said that you're right!

Comment: @HeyICanChan I am someone who is far more familiar with 3.5 than Pathfinder myself, so if that's what they were going for, it worked ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion here, @Southpaw Hare.  I will agree that Stag's Leap doesn't give extra movement, but from the way the ability is worded, you DO make the jump as a free action. Normally, a jump is performed as part of a move action (check the Action section of the Acrobatics skill), but specific trumps general. This is no different to the Stand Up feat, which allows one to stand as a free action.

Comment: @YogoZuno I still disagree, but I accept that it's very unclear and up to very gray interpretation.  I encourage you to make your own answer with a counter-proposal if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: @YogoZuno (Broadly, that's a point on which reasonable people can disagree. That is, must an ability that references the existing rules still play by those rules except as the ability describes, *or* does such an ability provide a brand new option that's disconnected from those rules? Only context, experience, and the developers can affirm either position. Absent hints—like here—I, personally, tend toward the former because, when pressed, the devs usually also go for the most restrictive reading. That way, my player's aren't disappointed when they do and pleasantly surprised when they don't.)